# Rewrite rules - going outside the docroot

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Assuming the following directory structure,

```
htdocs/
  images/
  css/
  .htaccess
system/
  index.php
  ...
```

I would like to route all incoming requests through that php script. I have been trying some rewrite rules within the htaccess, but I can't seem to be able to route to files that are outside the document root. I couldn't find a reason for this in the apache manuals, so eventually resorted to "Include" an apache config file, where the rules are different.

Is there a way of rewriting outside of the docroot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a lot of frameworks do is use rewrite to route all requests to one file where you can do more complex routing of your own. An example .htaccess file might be:

```
# ignore anything that's an actual file (eg CSS, js, images) 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
# redirect all other traffic to the index page
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Where index.php is inside your doc root (htdocs/index.php) and from which you can safely include System/index.php where appropriate.

Comment: remember to make sure you can't include any old file based on querystring - otherwise people might try things like /etc/passwd or /etc/httpd/httpd.conf etc - bad!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think your answer tackles the question at all.  He's asking about going *outside* the docroot.

Comment: @Simon - this answer suggests that files outside the docroot be included via an `htdocs/index.php` file that resides within the docroot. This prevents _direct_ access to files outside the docroot but still allows requests properly vetted in `htdocs/index.php` to include those files if appropriate.

Comment: Oh I see, so the PHP script does the `include()` rather than the mod_rewrite module.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot route outside the docroot without potentially enormous risk.

You should place the `index.php` within the `htdocs` folder and rewrite it there, not outside.  If you were to rewrite to handle the index, accessing outside the docroot, and you made one little mistake it's potentially exploited by any hacker rewriting the request string.  Not pretty!

Comment: Making mistakes in `index.php` is easy enough as well.